# Absolute Positioning of Grandchild in Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to absolutely position a child in a child in a `flexbox`.

The problem is that element jumps its parent and aligns instead to the grandparent. I know that this is a `flexbox` issue as it works fine outside of the `flexbox`.

Maybe this pseudo will help clear things up:

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%;">

  <div style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <button style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;">X</button>
  </div>

  <div>This is irrelevant.</div>

</div>
```

The button should be in the upper-right corner of its parent div, but instead it gets positioned to the middle of the screen.

Is there a right way (or hack) to fix this?

**EDIT: I have tried and tried again to duplicate the problem here in the code snippet to no avail** (in the original post I didn't test the pseudo code -- just assumed it would reproduce). This leads me to believe that the **the problem lies somewhere else in my code.** I apologize for not testing further before posting. **Because of this I cannot accept an answer.**

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Absolutely positioned `divs` / elements will always search for the nearest parent position relatives to line up with. In this case you just need to move it to the grandparent, not the parent.

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; position: relative;">

  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <button style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;">X</button>
  </div>

  <div>This is irrelevant.</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cut the `position: relative;` from the second `div` and move it to the parent `div` the one has `flex`. Then the `absolute` element will work based on the parent `div` and will be on the **top-right-side, please see the snippet below**-

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; background: #ccc;position: relative;">

    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <button style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;" >X</button>
    </div>

    <div>This is irrelevant.</div>

</div>
```